# Why is the mean of a Chi Square distribution equal to the degree of freedom?

Tags: mean, expected-value, degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution

Is this part of the definition of a Chi Square distribution?

Or is it deduced from another property? In which case, what is the proof?

Comment: [One definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is that $\chi^2(\nu)$ (for positive integral $\nu$) is the distribution of the sum of squares of $\nu$ independent standard Normal distributions.  What is the mean square of a standard Normal distribution?

Answer (score 7):

You don't *define* the mean to be the degrees of freedom (d.f.) -- it follows from the definition of the pdf and the definition of expectation of a random variable.

The pdf of a [chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) random variable with $k$ d.f. is:

${\frac {1}{2^{\frac {k}{2}}\Gamma \left({\frac {k}{2}}\right)}}\;x^{{\frac {k}{2}}-1}e^{-{\frac {x}{2}}}\; x>0, k>0$  (and $0$ elsewhere)

The [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_continuous_random_variable) of a continuous random variable is:

$\operatorname {E} [X]=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }xf(x)\,\mathrm {d} x.$

So the mean of a chi-square random variable is:

$\operatorname {E} [X]=\int _{0}^{\infty }x{\frac {1}{2^{\frac {k}{2}}\Gamma \left({\frac {k}{2}}\right)}}\;x^{{\frac {k}{2}}-1}e^{-{\frac {x}{2}}}\,\mathrm {d} x $

Pulling the constants out and combining the $x$ powers

${\frac {1}{2^{\frac {k}{2}}\Gamma \left({\frac {k}{2}}\right)}}\; \int _{0}^{\infty }x^{{\frac {k+2}{2}}-1}e^{-{\frac {x}{2}}}\,\mathrm {d} x $

the term in the integral can be recognized as another chi-square (missing the normalizing constant). If you multiply and divide by the relevant normalizing constant so that the integral is 1, you're left with a ratio of normalizing constants out the front (for different d.f.) ... which you should be able to simplify.

---

However, if your question is really "why choose that pdf to be called a chi-square?", whuber's comment is relevant -- the sum of squares of independent standard normals is a random variable that fairly naturally arises in a number of contexts*, and *that* is something we would therefore like to have a name for. The degrees of freedom relates to the number of independent normals involved and each of those squared components has mean 1.

* So for example, [Helmert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Robert_Helmert) identified it as related to the distribution of sample variance for iid samples from a normal distribution (though the use of the symbol $\chi^2$ and hence the name "chi-squared" don't come until Pearson's work about a generation later).

Comment: I understood the question in a different sense.  We have the freedom to parameterize any distribution differently; for instance, it would work perfectly fine to define the $\chi^2_\nu$ distribution to have a PDF proportional to $x^\nu e^{-x}$.  (From some points of view, this is simpler and more "natural.")  But then the mean would no longer equal the parameter.  Thus, the answer ought to address why one would choose to parameterize this family of distributions by the mean and not by some one-to-one function of it.

Comment: @whuber I don't share your interpretation of the question -- while I agree that one could see it that way, I don't think it was the intent. (Such an interpretation would make your comment under the question invalid, as well, which suggests you didn't take it that way before.)

Comment: I probably was too sketchy.  The point of that comment to the question, when coupled with the interpretation I have outlined here, is that it provides one good reason why one would want to parameterize the family in the usual way.  Indeed, it ought to be of particular interest that the $\chi^2$ distribution is *nothing other* than a reparameterization of the Gamma distribution!

Answer (score 1):

Chi squared distribution is Gamma distribution with parameters $(\lambda, \alpha) = (\frac12, \frac{n}2)$.

And we know that expected value of Gamma is $\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$ .

Hence the expected value of a chi squared r.v. is $ \frac{n/2}{1/2} = n$.